# Problem sending mail with phpmailer and iptables

Tags: iptables

I have a wordpress site on a ubuntu and apache web server.

I had to block outbound traffic with iptables on the "high" ports, from 11000 onwards for security reasons.

Unfortunately, since I set this rule, the contact form no longer works. I get the following errors

```
Connection: opening to mail.xxxxxxx.it 25, timeout = 300, options = array ....
Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client (): unable to connect to mail.xxxxxxx. (Connection timed out)
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
```

I use an external smtp server to send mail, so I installed the WP-Mail-SMTP plugin, which in turn uses PhpMailer. In the plugin settings it is well specified that it must use port 25, SMTP authentication, and no encryption.
In short, if I apply above rule, I cannot send mail. If I delete it, I can send mail again.

Does anyone know if there is a damn network port greater than 10000 that is used by PhpMailer or ubuntu, which is not clearly documented?

Answer (score 1):

When you make a outgoing connection to a SMTP server, you connect to the *remote* servers port 25. The local port, on your machine is taken from  a pool of [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).  When you attempt an outgoing connection, the operating system will allocate a high port number automatically, and more or less randomly, for the socket.

If you block the [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), you generally can't make outbound connections from a machine.

Usually the range is 49152-65535, according to IANA recommendations. Some operating systems, notably Windows XP and 2003 (and earlier) used lower ports for this. For Ubuntu I believe the default is 32768-60999:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range 
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
```

When this is blocked by iptables, the outgoing connection is not working. This is what you're observing here.

You can of course change this port range, but the security benefits of doing so is nil. What you probably want is to block **incoming** traffic to these ports. If you use ufw, this can be achieved by a drop all incoming, plus allow the specific incoming ports that you **do** want to listen to.

You will likely notice that other stuff, such as `sudo apt update` is broken due to these ports being blocked. If you absolutely do want to change the ephemeral ports range - for no benefit - you can have a look at [this answer at the U&L SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211647/how-safe-is-it-to-change-the-linux-ephemeral-port-range).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Actually I blocked the outbound ports because I had detected illegal spam traffic through these ports, and I wanted to block it in the meantime that I was trying to figure out the cause. At the same time, I would like to allow mail to be sent to a regular external smtp server (there is no local mail server on host, but can only send emails via an external server). I'm afraid, however, that some hackers have overcome the hurdle and can send e-mails. Since we are there, can not you give me a tip to set up the firewall so I get what I need ??? Thank you.

Comment: If someone who is not you is using the computer to send spam, the problem isn't the firewall. The problem is that they have access to the computer for the purpose of sending spam! There is no way for a firewall to differentiate between spam and non-spam e-mail. You need to find out how they're using your computer for sending spam, and fixing **that**. As you discovered blocking the ports effectively cuts of legitimate use. Changing the ephemeral ports or using a firewall will **not** help you.

Comment: I suggest you make a new question, stating your spam problem and your setup, if you need help with this problem.

Comment: I tried blocking all inbound traffic on ports 11000 onwards, but still outbound mails do not work. Ephemeral ports come into play even if inbound connections are blocked ???

Comment: No, blocking inbound traffic does not affect outgoing traffic - provided you allow responses. What exactly is your current firewall configuration? And as I said - I believe this is more appropriate for a new question...

Comment: Please edit them into your original question.

Comment: I open a new question